# How actionError() function will call in my controller in yii2?

Tags: error-handling, yii2

backend/controllers/AccessController.php

```
public function actionFault(){
$exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;

if ($exception !== null) {
    $statusCode = $exception->statusCode;
    $name = $exception->getName();
    $message = $exception->getMessage();

    $this->layout = 'layout';

    return $this->render('error', [
        'exception' => $exception,
        'statusCode' => $statusCode,
        'name' => $name,
        'message' => $message
    ]);
}
```

backend/config/main.php

```
 'components' => [
    // ...
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'access/fault',
    ],
    // ...
],
```

If I am not wrong than actionError() will call when any error comes am i right ?
But in my case actionError is not calling what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is `AccessController` in `backend` app? Is `$exception` not `null`?

Comment: yes AccessController is in backend and error function is not calling

Comment: PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: this error is coming on my one page i think error function should call when this error come but it has not called. Am i right ?

Comment: I would start by modifying my action according to the default [ErrorAction](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/ErrorAction.php) - maybe there is something missing.

Comment: One more thing @BIzley. In one page there is 403 error comes that this error function is calling. Is anything i need to add for PHP error/warning/notice

Comment: Default error displaying ini PHP settings should be fine. You can always change them like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/3364821).

Comment: What should i do now /

Comment: Give more info, like more details with this PHP Notice log.

Comment: 2016-10-27 10:58:17 [127.0.0.1][36][sds54sa7363unnlebpecdl0][error][yii\base\ErrorException:8] exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/backend/views/invoice/_form.php:105

Comment: Remove this `actionFault()` method, revert the `errorHandler` implementation to default `site/error` and add `ErrorAction` in the `actions()` method inside `SiteController` - if everything works then you can start working on your own implementation based on the default one.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Sadly it is still not working @Bizley :(

Comment: So you are telling me the default Yii 2 error handler implementation does not work? It looks like you have broken it somehow.

Comment: I have 3 setup of YII 2 in my htdocs directory. It is not working on any setup. Is there anything which i am missing ?

Comment: I can not tell you without looking at your code. Check the default implementation by comparing your setup with advanced project template. [Config](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/config/main.php#L36) and [controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php#L58)

Comment: If i have http error llike 403 or 404 then it is working and error() function is calling ? Do you have idea what is the problem in other type of php error ?

Comment: ok @Bizley thank you